# Mongodb fetch data only in pycharm but not in mongo shell

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pycharm, pymongo

I am developing a python application that uses mongodb. When I try to fetch data from the db, it works fine, but only from the pycharm. The mongodb shell and the robomongo does not recognize that there is any data in the db.

```
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo

db = MongoClient(host='127.0.0.1',port=27017)['countries']
collection = db['usa']

check = collection.find({'Name': 'John'}).count()
```

The value of check is 1 but when I am trying to run the find function in my mongodb shell it returns 0, and there are no collections there either.

It looks like there is a problem with the connection from the python although when I run the code from another computer it works great and it finds the same values in both platforms.

Comment: could you post the command that you're using to start the mongodb shell and the command that you execute within it?

Comment: My guess is that you are not using the right database in the shell. What does `db` return in the shell?

Comment: @JohnGreenall I didn't use any command to start the shell, I just clicked on the mongo.exe. In the shell I typed `use countries` and then `db.usa.find()`, which are the simplest commands to check whether there is any data in the db.

Comment: @Johnny127 Only explanation I can think of is that you're not accessing the same database/collection via python/ mongo.exe.